# is there a script component in AWS glue like in SSIS.?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssis, aws-glue

we are migrating our ETL to AWS, and exploring what components are available in AWS glue.
We have several .net scripts written in ssis for complex transformations.
I dont see any script component to write code in java/c# in Glue documentation.
if there is, could someone provide links to such documents/videos

aws documentation only shows scripts in python & scala,
is there some way we could write java/c# code for transformations

Answer (score 0):

AWS Glue only supports two programming languages, Python and Scala.
So, there is no script component.

Comment: is there a work around. I also see some links where we can write SparkSQL queries in the transformation. Can we write complex update statements using this? I'm very new to the topic. I have exp in SSIS & SQL & have Java background, hence asking how to migrate to Glue.